# Use Google Workbox for Offline Functionality in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, progressive-web-apps, workbox

One of my clients has a requirement for his Asp.Net MVC application to run in offline mode (without internet) and someone suggested that I should use Google Workbox. I am a bit confused if I can achieve the functionality for my application to work without the internet since it is a dynamic application and I don't think Google Workbox would be able to render the pages without internet connectivity. Can anyone advise if this is feasible?

Answer (score 0):

It's feasible if you have cached (previously loaded) pages and you expect the connection to resume again. Workbox can help with both of these things

Check out Workbox's [caching strategies](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies) page, and the [Offline Cookbook](https://web.dev/offline-cookbook/) for ideas for how to set up caching and revalidating pages:

Comment: Since server won’t be available so how is it going to render the pages in offline mode?

Comment: Previously loaded, and cached, versions of the pages can be rendered.

Comment: How should I deal with post and put methods?

Comment: There are other posts on Stackoverflow about this. You can't cache PUT/POST, but there are remedies. Easiest approach is to use GET wherever possible

Answer (score 0):

This is the point of workbox, to provide offline caching using Cache API and a Service Worker. You also do this with only a Service Worker and Cache API without the Workbox .js library.